# Function calls are not supported in decorators NgRx/Effects while building the App

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I am using Loopback SDK generator to generate the NgRx store/effects module. I customized the library to support the major changes that were required.

*Then I wrote custom effect to listen to GuardNotFound action and redirect to 404 page but its not working while building the app.*

Here is my **custom-effects.ts file**

```
@Injectable()
export class GuardFailEffect {
  constructor(private action$: Actions, private router: Router) {
  }
  @Effect({ dispatch: false })
  redirect$ = this.action$.pipe(
    ofType('[Campaign] Guard Fail', '[LoopbackAuth] Auth Guard fail'),
    tap(() => {
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/404');
    })
  );
}

export const CustomEffects= copy(LoopbackEffects); <--- array of effects classes generated from SDK
CustomEffects.push(GuardFailEffect); <--- inserting my custom effect


//function to deep copy the array of Classes aka objects
export function copy(o) {
  let output, v, key;
  output = Array.isArray(o) ? [] : {};
  for (key in o) {
    v = o[key];
    output[key] = typeof v === 'object' && v !== null ? copy(v) : v;
  }
  return output;
}
```

**App.module.ts**

```
imports : [
EffectsModule.forRoot(CustomEffects)
]
```

While building the app i get this error

```
    ERROR in src\app\app.module.ts(89,27): Error during template compile of 'AppModule'
  Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'copy' was called in 'CustomEffects'
    'CustomEffects' calls 'copy'.
```

**=>** ***If I don't deep copy the array it gives me an error while using push function***

```
[ts]
Argument of type 'typeof GuardFailEffect' is not assignable to parameter of type 'typeof LoopbackAuthEffects ... 5 more ... | typeof SubscriptionEffects'.
  Type 'typeof GuardFailEffect' is not assignable to type 'typeof SubscriptionEffects'.
    Types of parameters 'router' and 'subscription' are incompatible.
      Type 'SubscriptionApi' is not assignable to type 'Router'.
        Property 'rootComponentType' is missing in type 'SubscriptionApi'.
class GuardFailEffect
```

Can someone point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `forRoot` pattern in your case to construct the module you want to be imported. This should allow you to run custom code.

```js
@NgModule({
})
export class CustomEffectsModule {
  static forRoot() {
    const customEffects= this.copy(LoopbackEffects);
    customEffects.push(GuardFailEffect)
    return EffectsModule.forRoot(customEffects);
  }

  private static copy(o) {
    let output = Array.isArray(o) ? [] : {};
    for (let key in o) {
      let v = o[key];
      output[key] = typeof v === 'object' && v !== null ? copy(v) : v;
    }
    return output;
  }
}
```

#### App.module.ts

```js
imports : [
  CustomEffectsModule.forRoot()
]
```

Comment: I tried this. Now I am getting following error "ERROR in Error during template compile of 'AppModule'
  Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'CustomEffectsModule' was called."

Comment: I put together a demo on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-t15jww) which seems to be working for me.

Comment: Have you tried building it using angular cli and webpack config? Because I get error while building the app using npm run build:ssr command